# When I import data from excel to rstudio, it eliminate decimal points in numbers

Tags: r, excel

I have 2 columns in excel that have some values like 1002.45, 1021.34. When I try to import it to rstudio,it eliminates decimals points and show only integer.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please include the code you are using to import the data from excel?  Help for asking a good question can be found from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We can only help if we see what you're doing and the sample data you're working with. Note that in R, what you *see* on the console is not necessarily how the data is *stored* in the object. There are many reasons why this might be the case, and I don't think it's a good idea for us to try to enumerate all of them.

Comment: It turned out that I had to restart RStudio and now everything works perfectly